# Problems with Ajax post in node js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am learning Ajax and I was trying to do a post request using AJAX to my node js backend. But then for some reason, I tried console logging the data from the post request and nothing shows up. Can someone tell me what could be my error?

**home.ejs**

```
<html>
<title>HomePage</title>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

<form>
    Enter the food you are looking for: <input type="text" id="fooddata" name="fooddata"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit">

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Submit").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
        data.name = $('#fooddata').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/home',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});

app.get("/home",function(req,res){
    res.render("Home.ejs");
});

app.post("/home",function(req,res){
    var name = req.body.data.name;

    console.log("data",name);
});
```

Comment: It's just `req.body.name`. If you `console.log(req.body)`, you'll see the full object.

Comment: can you share server side code?

Comment: @farhadamjady:- Its there, I have added both end of the code.

Comment: as @BenFortune the full object is `req.body` use `res.json(req.body)` to see data on client side

Comment: @farhadamjady:-  I still cant see any data in the console. log. This is what happens in the url when I enter the data and submit. http://localhost:3000/home?fooddata=apple

Comment: @farhadamjady:-app.post("/home",function(req,res){
    var name = req.body.name;
   res.json(req.body.name);
    console.log("data",name);
});

Comment: change this line `data: JSON.stringify(data),` to `data:data,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit form sending data in different format. Instead of that you may use button and click event over it.

Below is the code with few of the tweaks:

home.ejs

```
<html>
<title>HomePage</title>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

<form>
    Enter the food you are looking for: <input type="text" id="fooddata" name="fooddata"></input>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="Submit">

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('adsdsdsdasdasd')
    $("#Submit").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
        data.name = $('#fooddata').val();
        console.log(data)
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/home',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log('error');
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, ''));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.get("/home",function(req,res){
    res.render("home.ejs");
});

app.post("/home",function(req,res){
    var name = req.body.name;

    console.log("data",name);
    res.send({name:name})
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```